# Getting MongoDB Collection stats with .NET 2.0 driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Using the .NET 2.0 Driver and assuming:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(db);
```

How do you do the equivalent to the shell command:

db['fs.files'].stats();

Comment: Have you tried `database.GetStats()`?

Comment: GetStats() is not an available method on the object

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

```
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument { { "collstats", "fs.files" } });
var stats = database.RunCommand(command);
```